# open the facebookapp through a link in emailing

Tags: android, ios, css, html

I am making an emailing with a CTA to our. So people can like our page.

I use the code:

a href="fb://profile/id number"

and ios will open the facebook app on my phone. But this is not working on any Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full link, including the HTTP:// , and the / at the end.